# pom.xml не могу правильно указать путь к main.java

Tags: java, maven

Пишу телеграм бота на Java,простенького,в целом я самоучка,такие вещи как мавен и гит для меня ещё пока новые-новые,потому прошу помощи,по людски разъясните,как правильно указывать путь к мейну. Код файла pom.xml оставляю ниже. Фактический адрес класса
/home/seer/eclipse-workspace/SBKbott/src/main/java/bot/SBKbott/main.java
Как правильно сдесь,И вы подобных случаях,генерировать путь к файлу?Отдельная просьба,не кидать англоязычную длокументацию , с английским всё плохо,гугл переводчик искажает :с спасибо за внимание и понимание!

P.S. : также добавляю лог heroku ,который получаю при push-e, под pom.xml

P.S.S :содержимое файла Procfile = worker: sh target/bin/SBKbott

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SBKbott</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SBKbott</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>src/main/java/bot.SBKbott/main.java</mainClass>
                        <name>SBKbott</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>    
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
2021-01-19T13:56:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-19T13:56:06.032380+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/SBKbott`
2021-01-19T13:56:06.669574+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-19T13:56:08.282351+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-19T13:56:08.314753+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-01-19T13:56:08.318270+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-19T13:56:08.023062+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2021-01-19T13:56:08.212582+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class home.seer.eclipse-workspace.SBKbott.src.main.java.bot.SBKbott
2021-01-19T13:56:11.683729+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/SBKbott`
2021-01-19T13:56:12.390227+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-19T13:56:13.579073+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-19T13:56:13.616239+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-01-19T13:56:13.367466+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2021-01-19T13:56:13.486150+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class home.seer.eclipse-workspace.SBKbott.src.main.java.bot.SBKbott
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо / должны быть точки и проверьте правильно ли у вас настроена структура папок

```
<build>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                 <manifest>
                    <mainClass>main.java.TextParser</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
           </configuration>
      </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: я делаю по примеру бота,сам бот в еклипс запускается и даёт ответы на запросы , пытаюсь лить на хероку-не хочет. Так вот.в примере сказано добавить строчки в pom.xml , ctrl+c ctrl+v разумеется ,не уверен в структуре и слабо ее понимаю,если можно вас попросить вот ссылка ,там о деплое аж в самом низу говорится,можете посмотреть структуру?Ибо я просто не могу найти ошибку.. Пробовал менять слеш на точку,не зашло . ТАм в конце "main.java"это сам класс мейн,его в пути нужно указывать?

https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/504-sozdanie-telegram-bota-na-java-ot-idei-do-deploja?post=full#discussion

Comment: P.S.S :содержимое файла Procfile = worker: sh target/bin/SBKbott

Comment: Главный класс должен быть в таком формате src.main.java.bot.SBKbott.Main

Comment: Если не поможет, попробуйте отойти от инструкции - есть и другие варианты задеплоить бота на хероку. Но вообще это процесс сложный, проблема может не только в pom.xml быть

Comment: Сделал таковой путь.Так же в procfile заменил строчку,на "worker: sh target/bin/workerBot".
В pom.xml параметр <name>workerBot</name>
вывод логера хероку не изменился,всё так же ищет мейн. Что может быть ещё не так?Может ли это быть связанно с тем,что main.java у меня начинается с маленькой буквы?